# R barplot TRUE/FALSE condition table

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a simple question about the barplot function. I have a TRUE/FALSE table like this:

> print(a)
>
> FALSE  TRUE
>
> 35517  1160

Now I want to create a barplot with one column (so length for that column is then 36677). In the column 2 colors must contain the TRUE/FALSE condition. Is that simple to do that?

I thought something like:  barplot(a, beside=FALSE) But than i create 2 columns beside each other.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then specify `a` as a matrix:

```
a <- c("FALSE" = 35517,"TRUE" = 1160)
a <- as.matrix(a)
barplot(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use `mosaicplot()`

```
aa <- c(rep(FALSE, 35517), rep(TRUE, 1160))
a <- table(aa)

mosaicplot(a, dir = "h", off = 0, color = TRUE)
```

See `?mosaicplot`for more info

Answer (score 0):

Using ggplot

```
#install.packages("ggplot2")

library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame(value=c("TRUE", "FALSE"), counts=c(1160,35517), index=1)

qplot(data=df, x=factor(index), y=counts, geom="bar", fill=value)
```